# possible to extract files according filename listed in a text file by using matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have thousand files in a folder, however, i only need to extract out hundred files from the folder according to the filename listed in a text file into new folder. The filenames in text file is listed as a column..is that possible to be run by using matlab?what is the code shall i need to write? Thanks.

example:

filenames.txt is in the C:\matlab

folder include thousand files is named as BigFiles also in C:\matlab

files to be extracted from BigFiles folder is listed in column as below:

filenames.txt

a1sndh

sd3rfe

rgd4de

sd5erw

please advise...thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate all files in a folder of a specific type (if needed) using:

```
 %main directory to process
directory = 'to_process';

%enumerate all files (.m in this case)
files = dir(fullfile(directory,'*.m'));

numfiles = length(files);
fprintf('Found %i files\n',numfiles)
```

Then you could load the single column using one of the [many file I/O functions](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1400/1403.html) in Matlab.

Then just loop through all the input names and check it's name against all the read in files (files{i}.name), and if so, move it.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

From what I understood, you are looking for a solution along the lines:

#### filenames.txt

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
.
.
.
```

#### moveMyFiles.m

```
%# read filenames listed in a text file
fid = fopen('C:\matlab\filenames.txt');
fList = textscan(fid, '%s');
fList = fList{1};
fclose(fid);

%# source/destination folder names
sourceDir = 'C:\matlab\BigFiles';
destDir = 'C:\matlab\out';
if ~exist(destDir,'dir')
    mkdir(destDir);
end

%# move files one by one
for i=1:numel(fList)
    movefile(fullfile(sourceDir,fList{i}), fullfile(destDir,fList{i}));
end
```

You can replace the MOVEFILE function by COPYFILE if you simply want to copy the files instead of moving them...

Comment: i get the error as below:??? Error using ==> movefile No matching files were found. Error in ==> moveMyFiles at 19 movefile(fullfile(sourceDir,fList{i}), fullfile(destDir,fList{i}));

Comment: to be able to help you, you should give us more information (where the files are located with respect to the script, directories you are working with, whether the text file contains full paths to files or just their names, etc...)

Comment: i have edited the question..please help to take a look..thanks..the text file only contain names.